# Intercepting requested file path & Open file from different source in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, httpresponse

I have 4.7.2 application where on anchor tag we have file link like 'www.abc.com/a.txt'. If I click it file is opening in new tab.
But now expected result is - When user hit that link, I want to intercept this link & change it to 'www.xyz.com/a.txt' & return response in new tab. Basically open file in new tab (no download).

Currently I'm able to download file using below code but I want to open in new tab.

```
Stream stream = null;
            int bytesToRead = 10000;
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
            try
            {
                string apiGatewayFilePath = "www.xyz.com/a.txt";
                HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiGatewayFilePath);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(apiGatewayFilePath);
                HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

                if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
                    fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

                stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();
                var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                resp.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
                resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
                resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

                int length;
                do
                {
                    if (resp.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                        resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        resp.Flush();
                        buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        length = -1;
                    }
                } while (length > 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean `but I want to open in new tab.`? you are using `WebRequest` which might call the HTTP server  in background

Comment: Returning response in new tab, So I want to download file from second source & open in new tab